# Navigation Item in a NIB is always nil

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, nib

I've set up a `UINavigationBar` in a view controller NIB and set outlets for the bar and its associated `UINavigationItem`. In the view controller's `viewDidAppear:` I debug the objects. The navigation bar is set to an object, but the navigation item is `nil`. The navigation bar's `items` array contains one `UINavigationItem`, which points to a valid object.

Why isn't the navigation item in the NIB being set up?

[image]

Here's the code I'm using in my view controller:

```
@interface NKViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationItem;
}
@end

@implementation NKViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UINavigationItem *itemsNavigationItem = [[navigationBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Items Navigation Item: %@", itemsNavigationItem);
    NSLog(@"ivar Navigation Item: %@", navigationItem);
}
@end
```

Which logs:

```
Items Navigation Item: <UINavigationItem: 0x71a0fb0>
ivar Navigation Item: (null)
```

Comment: Is it in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @Kevin no, it's just a bare navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigationItem` is (already) a (readonly) property on `UIViewController` (which is backed up by `_navigationItem` ivar) and probably the reason for this problem. Try to rename the property and it should be fine (actually in my version of Xcode it throws an error if I even try to add this as an outlet)

[image]

**Update**: Already tested with another name and it appears to be OK indeed

[image]

**More Update**: It's the name of the ivar

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationItemX;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationItem *itemsNavigationItem = [[navigationBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Items Navigation Item: %@", itemsNavigationItem);
    NSLog(@"ivar Navigation Item: %@", navigationItemX);

}
```

Which logs:

```
Items Navigation Item: <UINavigationItem: 0x71b11c0>
ivar Navigation Item: <UINavigationItem: 0x71b11c0>
```

Finally we can see that `navigationItem` is indeed something else by doing this:

```
NSLog(@"Items Navigation Item: %@", itemsNavigationItem);
NSLog(@"ivar Navigation Item: %@", navigationItemX);
NSLog(@"'Hidden' ivar: %@", [self valueForKey:@"navigationItem"]); // or self.navigationItem
```

Which logs:

```
Items Navigation Item: <UINavigationItem: 0x7185190>
ivar Navigation Item: <UINavigationItem: 0x7185190>
'Hidden' ivar: <UINavigationItem: 0x759e040>
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I should have mentioned that I'm using a bare ivar called `navigationItem` in my view controller, not a property.

Comment: But your screenshot shows 2 outlets right? Which means that you got two properties (`navigationBar` & `navigationItem`) correct? Still when I use `navigationItem` outlet with `@synthesize navigationItem = navigationItem;` it still **works** fine.

Comment: No, I just connected the outlets to the ivars. I posted an edit with the view controller code above.

Comment: @nevanking It's the name of the ivar, I can also see the problem which goes away when changing the name to something else -> http://cl.ly/image/1F3n1x071T0J

Comment: You're right! No idea what's going on here but thanks very much for the help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you man. See the last part, is really interesting XD

Comment: Strange. I don't get this at all. It's only declared as a bare ivar in the `UIViewController` header, no property; `UINavigationItem *_navigationItem;`